# Chrome trava com loop correto de JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando rodar o seguinte código, só que não consigo! É como se o navegador parasse de funcionar.

```
var scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54,
58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69,
34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51,
69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61,
46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18,
41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];

for (var i=0; i < scores.length; i = i++) {
    console.log("Buble Solution #" + i + " Score: " + scores[i]);
}
```

Porém quando eu tento executar o sinônimo com o `i = i + 1`, dá certo!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando usas `i++` acontecem duas coisas:

- o `i` sobe de valor (soma `+1`)
- essa ação retorna o `i` **inicial**

Pois, retorna o `i` inicial (antes de ser somado mais 1).

Experimenta:

```
var i = 0;
alert(i++); // 0
alert(i); // 1
```

Ou seja, no teu loop estás fazer o `i` tomar o valor do retorno de `i++`, ou seja: `i = i++`, o que é o mesmo que dizer `i = 0`... eternamente.

Daí o problema.

Quando usas `i = i + 1` já não tem problema, e quando usas somente `i++` (sem usar `i =`) também já não tem problema.

Comment: Muito bom! Obrigado! Me ajudou muito!

Comment: ou `++i` que incrementa a variável e depois retorna o novo valor. Ainda acredito que na sua situação, utilizar `forEach` seria mais performático..